# GCP's VM instance is frequently crashing/stopping

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu

We have created a Ubuntu-based GCP VM instance which has 2xNvidiaT4 GPU. We have noticed that after a while, it stops responding. However on the GCP console, the status shows as Running; but when we try to access via GCP SSH also it doesn't respond. When we STOP n START, it works fine.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Low on memory, high CPU usage, many reasons. Check Stackdriver for messages. Most likely you have very high CPU usage.

Comment: Please provide information about your VM like CPU/RAM.

Comment: CPU - n1-highmem-8 (8 vCPUs, 52 GB memory)

Comment: Thanks! Let's investigate further. 1. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> go to section **`Logs`** click on `Serial port 1 (console)` and look for some errors there and/or share log at [hastebin](hastebin.com). 2. Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> go to section **`Logs`** click on `Stackdriver Logging` and check there as well. 3. Check at load on CPU and utilization of RAM while your VM fully loaded.